# Manage mailbox without Exchange Management Tool

Tags: email, powershell

In my previous job I have created a few powershell scripts that handle mailboxes using Exchange Management Tools and the cmdlet installed.

Now I have a similar environment but I can't install the Exchange tools in the server where scripts should run. How can I do? Is there a convenient way (a set of powershell cmdlets) to download my mailbox content and handle emails?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to Exchange servers using remote PowerShell

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.160).aspx

This will load the Exchange cmdlets into your remote session.  Once you are connected you can simply run your regular scripts.

Comment: Thank you, that's an idea. Do I need admin rights to remotely connect to PS or is there a less strong permissions to by added to my user?

Comment: I don't believe permissions are enabled by default.  Someone may have to grant you them.  See this link.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638078(v=exchg.160).aspx